# frontend maven plugin Failed to execute goal

Tags: java, maven

In our project we use frontend maven plugin 
this is my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp/ui</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>src/main/webapp/ui/node_modules</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!--Needed To run Grunt Tasks-->
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v5.3.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>3.3.12</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>grunt build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>grunt</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

when i clean install the project i got this error :

```
led to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project web: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.0 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
```

My Maven's version is 3.3.3 also i tried it with version 3.1.0 and it got the same error , so i used proxy in my settings.xml BUT it got the same error.

Comment: How do you run the maven command? From inside the IDE? In this case, your IDE may use build-in maven, this is the case for example for netbeans.

Comment: @MikhailChibel Oh thanks , i got it

Answer (score 3):

I solve it , my IDE has it's bundled maven, so i just tell it to use mine !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when building a Jenkins plugin with Netbeans. Netbeans also uses its own bundled version of Maven. Go to Tools-Options-Java-Maven and select another version of Maven under "Maven Home".

The bundled version was 3.0.5.

[image: Netbeans Options]